# add a jslink in item add form using Schema.xml

Tags: sharepoint-addin

How to add a jslink in Calendar list new item add form using Schema.xml

I'm Try this code:

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseLegacyForm="FALSE" JSLink="~site/DemoBranding/ProviderHostedjavascript.js" />
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript link is correct? Please try to open that javascript in browser with proper url.

Comment: yes my javascript link is correct but I am using in sharepoint App list

Comment: Try to check it by calling `alert('hi');` in the JavaScript file.

Comment: js file attach is doesn't attach in Calendar list.

Comment: Are you implementing a code.